# IBM MQ. DISCINT attribute throws error when added to Server connection channel alter command

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

Alter channel page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085170_.htm shows that I can use Disconnect interval (**DISCINT**) in **server connection channel** `alter command`, however I get error message which claims that it **can** only **be used** for **server or sender channel** types, but **not for server connection channel** types.

Maybe MQ command level is too low for DISCINT attribute? How can I check that?

Operating System is Linux for that particular workgroup server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [knowledge center page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc10480_.htm?lang=en) for MQ v 7.0.1 indicates that `alter chl DISCINT`  is only valid on zOS.

Also, this [page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzae.doc/ic11690_.htm?lang=en) says:  This attribute is valid for channel types Server connection (z/OS® only)

Maybe you are using an older version of MQ?  There are many different ways to check your MQ version - from the command line try `dspmqver`.

Comment: thanks. I used "IBM Knowledge Center" and searched four times for "ALTER CHANNEL", each time with a different products filter value (Websphere MQ), then clicked on a result which has common alter channels parameters table scrolled to the bottom of the page, selected "Server-connection channel" and found that DISCINT command is "z/OS only" when command level is lower that 710. You can use DISCINT for 710 or greater with no problems on all OS'es.

Comment: @Benas - Check the the pages linked by Valerie again.  On the first page the `DISCINT` parm has a footnote #3.  The second page has some bullets halfway down.  Both of these indicate that `DISCINT` is only valid on z/OS at this version.  Perhaps you meant  "You can use `DISCINT` for **7.5** or greater with no problems on all OS'es"?